# How to using C to open openwrt /dev/i2c-0 and send 128 bytes at a time

Tags: c, i2c, openwrt

I am using C to open **openwrt /dev/i2c-0 on MT7688** and send 64 bytes, it is work fine.
but send 128 bytes does error.
I found that sending more than 64 bytes would be wrong. and i got "**Invalid argument**" error message.
I can send 64 bytes so it's not SMbus. 
I use 128x64 OLED screen, it need send 130 bytes at a time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define I2C_SLAVE   0x0703

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fd;

    /* is't work fine
    char buffer[63] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0x0B,0x0C,0x0D,0x0E,0x0F,
                   0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x16,0x17,0x18,0x19,0x1A,0x1B,0x1C,0x1D,0x1E,0x1F,
                   0x21,0x22,0x23,0x24,0x25,0x26,0x27,0x28,0x29,0x2A,0x2B,0x2C,0x2D,0x2E,0x2F,
                   0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x3A,0x3B,0x3C,0x3D,0x3E,0x3F,
                   0x41,0x42,0x43
                  };
    */

    // does not send
    char buffer[128] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,....,0x80};

    fd = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
      // Open port for reading and writing
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open i2c bus /dev/i2c-0\n");
      return 1;
    }

    ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, 0x3C);
    write(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: What kind of error did you receive?

Comment: What device is on i2c-0? Do you know for a fact that there are more than 64 registers per bank? How do you know there's an error? Is either the ioctl or the write call returning an error?  What kind?  You can check with a call to perror

Comment: Hi all, i use perror method then i got "Invalid argument" message.